# Directory creation from pattern

Tags: r, directory

I´ve been creating new directories manually using the script "dir.create(file.path(dir, subdir))", but now I need to automatically create new directories adopting a "pattern" 2+2 in their names, for example: directory 1 should be named "1-2", directory 2 should be named "3-4, directory 3 should be named "5-6", directory 4 sould be named "7-8", and so on...

Is this possible, buddies?

Comment: what exactly are you following? I do not see a pattern ie 1-2, 3-5,6-7,7-8 what is the pattern?

Comment: oops... sorry... last directory should be named "8-9". The pattern is: the name of new directories should has the next 2 numbers from the previeous directory

Comment: probably you need 1-2,3-4,5-6,7-8... this is a pattern. what you have is not a pattern

Comment: yep. Indeed. You are right. Do your know how do I create directories adopting this pattern?

Comment: just do `do.call(paste, c(sep="-",data.frame(t(matrix(seq(no_of_directories * 2),2)))))` from here you could use the `dir.create` command and the `unlink` commands